# Why is pin diagram of 7402 NOR gate reversed as compared to other gates?

Tags: logic-gates, pins

The following is a picture of pin design of 74 series TTL IC Family logic gates [taken from this site](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Digital/dig21.php):

[image]

We observe that in every logic gate, the input pins are (1,2), (4,5), (9,10), (12,13) and output pins are (3), (6), (8), (11) but in case of 7402 NOR gate, the input and output pins are reversed i.e. input pins are (2,3), (5,6), (8,9), (11,12) and output pins are (1), (4), (10), (13). Why is this so? Why is the pins reversed in case of 7402 NOR  gate? The following picture clearly depicts what I am trying to say(taken from [this datasheet](http://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT02.pdf)):[image]

Is it due to structural planning, stability or some other reason?The I couldn't find any reasoning on the internet  and need some help. Also, what would happen if we connect NOR gate as we do in other gates?

Comment: these were grandfathered from TTL system design requirements and no reason to change for CMOS

Comment: Hi there and welcome to the site. These ICs were first made in the 1960s, when silicon chip manufacturing was very much in its infancy, so I can only guess. There's no application benefit I can think of. Can I ask why you wanted to know - was it just curiousity or does it affect something you're working on?

Comment: @TonyM It is just curiosity. Just went through different logic gates and observed why NOR gate has different pin diagram. There has to be some reason why it is different.

Comment: Probably something dull. They were laid out by different engineers... It was an attempt at bringing better manufacturing yield through a different layout idea... They wish it was the same but the guy had done all the layout by then... I'd guess that it'll be a far less exciting reason than you might imagine :-)

Comment: I don't know but I have wanted to have a stern talk with the guy who did it ever since I took digital in College in 1976. Now I teach Digital Electronics at a local University and my students feel the same way. We just had a lab that used a 74LS02 and even though I warned them, several wired up their breadboards wrong and were not happy about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We observe that in **every** logic gate, the input pins are (1,2),
> (4,5), (9,10), (12,13) and output pins are (3), (6), (8), (11) **but**
> in case of **7402** NOR gate, the input and output pins are reversed

Er, no we don't. The 74266 doesn't follow the supposed 'standard' pinout. Also the 7401 Quad Open Collector NAND, 7439 Quad Open Collector NAND, 7428 Quad NOR and 7433 Quad Open Collector NOR gates all have the same pinout as the 7402.

I suspect the original reason for the different pinouts was to get the most efficient layout on the chip.

Here's an annotated photo of a [7400](https://project5474.org/index.php?title=7400_NS_443) die:-

[image]

And here's a [74LS01](https://project5474.org/index.php?title=74LS01_TI_8610):-

[image]

We observe that they are laid out in opposite directions relative to VCC and GND, which explains the different pinout. The fact that several gates followed the same layout as the 7401 suggests that there was an advantage to doing it in this direction.